# C# string serializer converted to Qt

Tags: c#, c++, string, linq, qt

I have this

```cs
 public static string Serialize(List<string> lst)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
        foreach (var str in lst)
        {
            string inter;
            inter = str.Count().ToString().Count().ToString() + str.Count().ToString() + str;
            output.Append(inter);
        }
        return output.ToString();
    }
```

What this code does is if I have a string `troy` in it, it will return

```cs
14troy
```

1 being how many digits in the identifier and 4 being the number of characters in the string.

Or if I use `stackoverflow` it will return

```cs
213stackoverflow
```

2 being the number of digits in the length identifier and 13 being the number of characters in the message..

I'm trying to convert this to Qt code and I don't understand what .Count() is returning. I know it's in System.Linq.

I also need to know how I would achieve this in Qt C++.

Edit: After getting Tim Meyer's help I figured out how to do it.. He're's the code

```cs
QString ObjectSerializer::Serialize( QList<QString> lst ) {
    QString output;
    foreach( QString str, lst )
    {
        int strLen = str.length();
        int identLeng = QString(QString::number(strLen)).length();
        output.append( QString( "%1%2%3" )
           .arg( identLeng )
           .arg( strLen )
           .arg( str ) );
    }
    return output;
}
```

ALSO if you're interested in the deserializer (does the opposite) here's the code:

```cs
QList<QString> ObjectSerializer::Deserialize( QString str ) {
    if(str.isNull() || str.isEmpty())
        return QList<QString>();

    QList<QString> items;

    int index = 0;
    while(index < str.length()) {
        int indexLen = QString(str[index]).toInt();
        index++;
        QString subStr = str.mid(index, indexLen);
        int keyLen = subStr.toInt();
        index += indexLen;

        QString key = str.mid(index, keyLen);
        index += keyLen;

        items.append(key);
    }
    return items;
}
```

Comment: The [Count Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx)  returns the number of elements in a sequence. For example, the number of `char` elements in the sequence `"stackoverflow"` is 13, as `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: In the case of a `string`, yes.

Comment: I'm taking a guess here but since 'var str' is being used in the foreach loop with a string list, does that make 'str' a string?

Comment: Yes. `var` is like `auto` in C++11, i.e. the type of the variable is inferred by the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
QString YourClass::serialize( const QStringList& list )
{
    QString output;

    foreach( QString str, list )
    {
        output.append( QString( "%1%2%3" )
           .arg( QString::number( str.length() ).length() )
           .arg( str.length() )
           .arg( str ) );
    }

    return output;
}
```

I didn't test this by the way, but it should work like that.

Comment: This works fine but when I use something like "stackoverflow", this has 13 characters. So after serialization it should return "213stackoverflow". But when I do it with your snippet it only says "113stackoverflow". How do I fix this?

Comment: Hm can you share what you did to fix it? I didn't expect it to return 113 rather than 213